# Initialize a gitlab project both locally and remotely with a single command

Tags: bash, git

This shell script, with only a few configurations, has the goal of initializing a project on Gitlab.com without having to go through the go through the website's ui.

This means: Let's say you just a project with a few source files, but you haven't done anything with git yet. The goal of this script is to allow you to write something like `git-init-remote <my_repository_name>` on the command line and have both the project on your personal gitlab.com and the local git repository.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

repo=$1
token=<YOUR-PRIVATE-TOKEN> # You get this from https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens
username=<YOUR-USERNAME>

test -z $repo && echo "Repo name required." 1>&2 && exit 1

curl --request POST --header "Private-Token: $token" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"name\":\"$repo\"}" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects"

echo "\nDone initializing on remote."
echo "\nCreating local git repository..."

git init
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/$username/$repo.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master

echo "\nDone."
```

I would like to have any of your thoughts on how this can break and how scalable this can go. I had trouble finding similar scripts on the web so I felt like a had to write here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to CodeReview.SE and thanks for submitting your script for a code review!

## Good points

- Good output conveying how progress is being made.
- Clear variable names

## Suggestions

- Are there limitations for what characters can be in a repo name?  If so, you might want to check that before sending it to the API.  It is good that you're checking to make sure they passed something in.
- Aside from making sure `$1` is set, there is no error checking.  If the `curl` fails do you want to continue with the `git` commands?
- It isn't clear if you want this to run in bash or POSIX sh.  The question is tagged for bash, but your sh-bang line points at POSIX shell.  But yay for including the sh-bang line.
- One shell best practice is putting your variable substitutions in double quotes.  `git remote add origin "https://gitlab.com/$username/$repo.git"` shows how to change one of your lines of code.  You want the variables inside of double quotes so that spaces in a variable name don't cause the shell to split what you think is one argument into multiple arguments to the command.

## Ideas

- Do you really want the token stored in the source code?  Can you pull this from a secrets vault or store it in a separate file?  If you want to commit your source code to a code repository (like git) it would be much better if it didn't include secret tokens.
- I'd try seeing if I could get this to work as a git subcommand.  [Here is a medium article](https://medium.com/@santiaro90/write-your-own-git-subcommands-36d08f6a673e) on writing your own git subcommands.
- Use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to get automated best practice suggestions for your shell code.  It can also be run locally on the command line.